# É uma má prática sobrescrever variáveis declaradas como parâmetro de uma função?

Tags: php, funções, variáveis, estilo-de-codificação

Eu tinha o costume de ficar "reatribuindo" um valor de uma determinada variável que foi declarada como `nome` do parâmetro da função.

Exemplo:

```
function format($string)
{
    $string = ltrim(rtrim($string, ']'), '['); // A questionada atribuição

    return "[{$string}]";
}
```

Ou seja: `$string` é o primeiro parâmetro de `format`, e eu alterei o valor da variável `$string` (que é a variável do parâmetro) dentro dessa função.

Por outro lado, também poderia ter feito da seguinte forma:

```
function format($string)
{
    $new_value = ltrim(rtrim($string, ']'), '['); // A questionada atribuição

    return "[{$new_value}]";
}
```

Daí eu comecei a me questionar os tipos de problemas que poderiam ser gerados ao fazer coisas desse tipo.

Então:

- Existe alguma recomendação ou algum padrão que instrua a respeito dessa "reatribuição do parâmetro"?
- Em quais casos essa reatribuição poderia me ocasionar problemas - ou que resolveria o problema?

Comment: No caso da variável ser global e ela ter alguma outra utilidade, ai daria um problema enorme, de resto não acredito que haja algum problema, depende do escopo do projeto.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio, usar variável global, por si só, já é uma péssima prática. Nesse caso então...

Comment: Nunca é ha problema se você tem convicção do que esta fazendo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em geral não há problemas.

**Pode** haver se o tipo passado tem semântica de passagem por referência. Obviamente nesse caso a mudança afetará a variável que foi usada como argumento, se uma variável foi usada em vez de um literal, que aí não teria problemas porque obviamente ele não poderia ser usado em outro lugar, mas nesse caso houve mais a passagem da referência e não por referência.

Em um tipo *string* passa-se uma referência e não copia o dado como ocorre com um número por exemplo, mas a passagem não é por referência, então qualquer alteração nela, não reflete na variável usada na chamada.

Então nada muda. Na verdade o seu exemplo parece bem interessante para reatribuir um valor para a mesma variável do parâmetro porque no fundo é o mesmo dado.

Não vou entrar no mérito do nome do parâmetro ser ruim porque é um exemplo, mas em uma pergunta de estilo de condição isto pode ser importante. Se estiver usando nomes significativos, aí atribuir para outra variável pode fazer diferença em legibilidade, ter nomes que indiquem o que é aquele texto. Se o parâmetro se chamasse `$texto`, poderia chamar a nova variável de `$texto_formatado` para deixar claro que ali o conteúdo teve a mudança. Dar um significado para o conteúdo.

Reforço que em casos simples assim este tipo de legibilidade é exagero e não faz sentido, mas pode fazer em código mais complexos. Se bem que alguns dirão que códigos mais complexos já é uma má prática.

Eu sei que é só um exemplo mas já que estamos no assunto, nesse caso a variável sequer é necessária, esta função só precisaria ter a linha do `return` com a expressão. Por isso que eu falei que depende do contexto se você precisa dar legibilidade ou não. Em geral eu acho que não precisa ficar querendo documentar todas as operações criando variáveis intermediárias, só faço isto quando realmente é algo confuso, mas é gosto.

Claro que se você precisa usar o valor original do parâmetro outras vezes, não pode descartá-lo. E seria uma bobagem para evitar o descarte guardar este valor em outra variável e reatribuir um novo valor nessa que é o parâmetro.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Não tem problema.

Dentro de uma `function`, qualquer alteração de valor em uma variável passada normalmente `$variavel`, só terá efeito dentro do contexto, que no caso é dentro daquela `function`.

Uma ocasião em que teria efeito em outro contexto, por exemplo em quem chamou esta `function`, é se a variável fosse passada por referência `&$variavel`.

Abaixo citei alguns exemplos práticos, inclusive quando se trata de objetos:

```
// caso 1
funcaoQualquer($var) {
    $var = 10;
    var_dump($var); // imprime 10
}

$variavel = 1;
funcaoQualquer($variavel); // chama a função        
var_dump($variavel); // imprime 1


// caso 2
funcaoQualquer(&$var) {
    $var = 10;
    var_dump($var); // imprime 10
}

$variavel = 1;
funcaoQualquer($variavel); // chama a função
var_dump($variavel); // imprime 10


// caso 3
funcaoQualquer($var) {
    $var->propriedade = 10;
    var_dump($var->propriedade); // imprime 10
}

$variavel = new Object();
funcaoQualquer($variavel); // chama a função
var_dump($variavel->propriedade); // imprime 10
```

Comment: Nesse caso do objeto, geralmente já  é esperado que o parâmetro seja um objeto. E você não está alterando a variável para outro valor, e sim a propriedade do objeto instanciado

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Sim, só coloquei pra deixar claro o maior número de possibilidades.